# Understanding Unity3d physics: where is the force applied?

Tags: physics, unity, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm trying to understand which is the right way to apply forces to a `RigidBody`.

I noticed that there are `AddForce` and `AddRelativeForce` methods, one applied in world space coordinate system meanwhile the other in the local space.
The thing that I do not understand is the following: usually in physics library (es. [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtRigidBody.html#af016720c45cf7ccaf8701d81a28319d9)) we can specify the force vector and also the force application point.

How can I do this in Unity? Is it possible to apply a force vector in a specific point relative to the given RigidBody coordinate system?
Where does AddForce apply the force?

Comment: Any force on a rigid body can also be represented as a force at center of mass plus a torque. I would hope there is a convenience method not to have to calculate that yourself, though.

Comment: @Kevin Reid: do you have any reference where is explained how can I perform this calculus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation isn't terribly clear on it—and I'm not currently in a position to verify it—but I *believe* that the force applied from `RigidBody.AddForce()` ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)) is applied at that object's root location (at its `transform.position`).  If not at `transform.position`, then at the object's `RigidBody.centerOfMass` ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html)).

If you want to apply a force vector at a specific point, you probably want to use `RigidBody.AddForceAtPosition()` ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html)).  Similarly, there is `RigidBody.AddRelativeForce()` ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html)) if you just want it local to the object itself.

And, for even more control if you know the torque you want to apply, there are `RigidBody.AddTorque()` ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html)) and `RigidBody.AddRelativeTorque()` ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque.html)).

</wallOfLinks>

Comment: Yes thanks.. AddForceAtPosition is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't see it in the doc.. thanks for linking !!